# Form validation via java script Array with alert if not validated

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm at my wits as my coding experience sucks. I'm trying to validate a radio and a check box for a form validation requirement. I need  at least 1 check box and 1 radio must be checked if not an alert will pop up and state please select at least 1 check box and 1 radio and the form must not submit until it is validated..

Here is my do submut finction below not that I have 3 but I iwll not post the entire html unless it required.

```
function doSubmit() /

{
if (validateText()==false)
{
alert("Required data missing in Step 1");
}

if (validateRadio()==false)
{
alert("Required data missing in Step 2");
}

if(validateTops()==false)
{
alert("Required data missing in Step 3");
return;
}
```

Folowed by the remaining code with my sorry attempt. as I did not want to post the entire html file.

```
function validateRadio()
{
var chks = document.getElementsByName('sizes');
var hasChecked = false;
for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
{
if (chks[i].checked)
{
hasChecked = true;
break;
}
}

if (hasChecked == false)
{
alert("Please select at a Pizza Size.");
return false;
}

return true;
}

function validateTops()
{
var chks = document.getElementsByName('toppings');
var hasChecked = false;
for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
{
if (chks[i].checked)
{
hasChecked = true;
break;
}
}

if (hasChecked == false)
{
alert("Please select at a Pizza Size.");
return false;
}

return true;
}

</ script>

</ head> 
<body>
<form Name ="PizzaForm">
<h1> The JavaScrpt Pizza Parlor</h>
<p>
<h4> Step 1: Enter your name, address, phone number, and email:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>
Address:&nbsp;<Input name="address" size="50" type="text"><br>
City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="city" size="15"type="text">
State:<Input name="state" size="2"type="text"><br>
Zip:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="zip" size="5"type="text"> <br>
Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="phone" size="50"type="text"><br>
Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="email" size="31"type="text"><br>
</ font>
</ p>
<p>
<h4> Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Small">Small
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Medium">Medium
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Large">Large
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Jumbo">Jumbo<br>    </ font>
</ p>
<p>
<h4> Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Black Olives">Black Olives<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Plain">Plain    </ font>
</ p>
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
<input type="button" value="Clear Entries" onClick="doClear()">
</ form>
</ body>
</ html>
```

Please note that I'm looking for an array that will validate the form on submission and if it fails gvies an alet and stops the submisson. Finally the name of all the radio is sizezs and the name of all the checkbox is toppings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, `sizes` clearly isn't a `tagName`. A tagname would be something like `input`, what you want is to `getElementsByName` instead.

Comment: Try `var rads=document.getElementsByName("sizes"); for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) if (rads[i].checked) return true; return false;`

Comment: Secondly use the form's onsubmit event to `return doSubmit()`

Comment: Not sure how to do a  form's onsubmit event to return doSubmit() as my other vaidation does not have it. Also, how do I get my alert if nothing is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the "required" attribute to your radio and checkbox inputs.

```
<input name="sizes" type="radio" required="required">
```

Comment: I need this to be java script with an alert if the radio or check box is not submited. Also, I edited my code